# How to identify the origin of an Http request?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, cors

I have this code that adds Cors Mappings to my java spring application.

It works well to allow requests comming from `http://localhost:4200`.

But it is not working to allow requests from the second origin (test server).

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {    
        
    registry.addMapping("/**") //all paths
    .allowedMethods("*") //all methods/endpoints
    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200", //dev
    "http://serverip:8080"); //test server
}
```

I'm guessing `"http://serverip:8080"` in that code is not quite right.

So I wanted to identify the exact origin where the call is comming.

Then I can add that origin "as is" in the allowedOrigins list.

How can I do that?

I tried this but it's returning null.

```
@RequestMapping(value  = "/httprequestorigin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHttpRequestOrigin() throws UnknownHostException {
    
     String origin = "";
        
     RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)requestAttributes).getRequest();
            origin = request.getHeader("HttpHeaders.ORIGIN");
        }
    
      return origin;
    
}
```

Also tried like this and it also returns null.

`origin = request.getHeader("Origin");`

And when I read the http headers in Chrome Dev Tools I don't see "Origin" in there.

Understand this code is not working because the origin header is not available.

So how to identify the origin of the Http request in that case?

Comment: `serverip:8080` looks weird. Are you sure, that this is the endpoint of your frontend?

Comment: No. Where you see "serverip" you can replace by the actual ip number. I just didn't want to inform the ip address in here and so I wrote that.

Comment: You can try checking once again by checking it on incognito window  to see if `origin` header is there.

Is your backend service on the same ip as the serverip and same port (8080)? Because browsers might not send origin header for the same origin requests.

Comment: To echo @akop's question, is `http://serverip:8080` where a browser-based client lives? Only browsers (not all user agents) automatically include an `Origin` in cross-origin requests.

Comment: @jkfe `serverip:8080` seems that it pointing to your spring backend. But the origin should be your frontend. It is maybe `serverip:80` or `serverip:4200`.

Comment: @Tush You are correct. It was returning null because both frontend and backend are in the same serverip:port. Thus, both are in the same origin. The code works to identify origin when front and backend are in different origins.

Comment: @jub0bs Right. The call was from a browser, but both front and backend are in the same origin. That's why it returned null.

Comment: @akop The frontend is also on 8080 (frontend deployed to Tomcat). So ip and port were correct. Like replied to others, it was returning null because both front and backend are in the same origin.

Comment: @jkfe If both server and client are on the same [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), there shouldn't be a need to configure CORS, by definition.

Comment: @jub0bs Right. Learned that now. That was the reason.

Comment: @jub0bs (or TE) can you write it as an answer?

Comment: @akop Feel free to write an answer. You were on the right track before I chimed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments (creds also to [jub0bs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541573/jub0bs):

The backend and the frontend are served by the same endpoint (`serverip:8080`). Webbrowsers will only send the origin, if backend and frontend are different hosts.

Read more about CORS at mozilla. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS